# how to pass Array of values to filter using pickBy method

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I'm passing a array as parameter in pickBy function

```
    return fetch(API_BASE + url + (params ? '?' + stringify(pickBy(params, v=>v===false||!!v)) : ''), {
    method: 'GET',
    headers,
    credentials: 'include'
  }).then(resp=>{
    authGuard(resp);
    return resp;
  });
```

and my params object is

```
 currencyId: [12,44]
    dueDateEnd: null
    dueDateStart: null
    exceptionTypeIds: (2) ["Contract updates/correction WIP", "Closed Contract"]
```

now whenever I'm passing only one exceptionTypeIds then it's working but when I pass two values, then it's throwing error that exceptionTypeIds must be a string ,CurrencyId must be a number .
I want to achieve that whenever I pass any value it will work .

Comment: What is the expected output and share the code which you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

That's weird. I just tried with lodash 4.14.120 and the behavior is as expected:

```
const params = {
    currencyId: [12, 44],
    dueDateEnd: null,
    dueDateStart: null,
    exceptionTypeIds: ["Contract updates/correction WIP", "Closed contract"]
}

console.log(_.pickBy(params, v => v === false || !!v))
```

returns

```
{
    currencyId: [ 12, 44 ],
    exceptionTypeIds: [ 'Contract updates/correction WIP', 'Closed contract' ]
}
```

Even with only one exceptionTypeId or an empty array: no error.

I tried this in the Node.js REPL. Maybe there is something in the browser.